# Use of \G boundary matcher in Java

Tags: java, regex

I've been learning regex with java.
I wanted to know if it makes sense to use \G while using java's matcher.
I couldn't find any example of \G used with java :(

Doing something like this would not have the same output as using \G?

```
String a = "Pruebaprueba";
Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile("(\\w)").matcher(a);
while ( matcher.find() ) {
    // Do something with each letter
}
```

Thanks for reading!

Comment: [Here's](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33411197/4856258) one more example how `\G` might be helpful with splitting.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Directly from http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/essential/regex/index.html

> To require the match to occur only at
>   the end of the previous match, use \G:
>
> ```
> Enter your regex: dog 
> Enter input string to search: dog dog
> I found the text "dog" starting at index 0 and ending at index 3.
> I found the text "dog" starting at index 4 and ending at index 7.
>
> Enter your regex: \Gdog 
> Enter input string to search: dog dog
> I found the text "dog" starting at index 0 and ending at index 3.
> ```
>
> Here the second example finds only one
>   match, because the second occurrence
>   of "dog" does not start at the end of
>   the previous match.

So no, it would not do exactly the same as your example. I do think if you'd change the regex to "(.)" you'd get the same effect as "\G." in this contrived example. But "(\w)" would go on searching after a whitespace while "\G\w" would fail at that point.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I also found this link interesting for a better understanding of \G:
http://www.rhinocerus.net/forum/lang-perl-misc/589432-faq-6-20-what-good-g-regular-expression.html

Comment: @Macarse Link seems broken unfortunately